# Moving and cleaning some rows to one

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I need to move and cleaning some rows to make only one.

We have this dataset:

```
    customer  flow  session timestamp                 name  recommends cpf            delivery
0   C1000     F1000 S1000   2019-12-16 13:59:58+00:00 maria NaN        NaN            NaN
1   C1000     F1000 S2000   2019-12-16 13:59:58+00:00 NaN   NaN        NaN            NaN
2   C1000     F1000 S2000   2019-12-16 13:59:59+00:00 joao  NaN        NaN            NaN
3   C2000     F2000 S3000   2019-12-16 13:59:59+00:00 NaN   Simmmmmmm  NaN            NaN
4   C1000     F1000 S2000   2019-12-16 13:59:59+00:00 NaN   NaN        733.600.420-26 NaN
5   C1000     F1000 S1000   2019-12-16 14:00:00+00:00 NaN   NaN        ZZZ            NaN
6   C1000     F1000 S2000   2019-12-16 14:00:00+00:00 NaN   NaN        NaN            não
7   C1000     F1000 S1000   2019-12-16 14:00:01+00:00 NaN   NaN        305.584.960-40 NaN
8   C2000     F2000 S3000   2019-12-16 14:00:01+00:00 NaN   NaN        NaN            NaN
9   C1000     F1000 S1000   2019-12-16 14:00:01+00:00 NaN   NaN        NaN            sim
```

We need to make this output:

```
# +--------+-----+-------+-------------------+-------------------+-----+--------------+------------------+
# |customer|flow |session|first_answer_dt    |last_answer_dt     |name |cpf           |delivery_confirmed|
# +--------+-----+-------+-------------------+-------------------+-----+--------------+------------------+
# |C1000   |F1000|S1000  |2019-12-16T13:59:58|2019-12-16T14:00:01|maria|305.584.960-40|sim               |
# |C1000   |F1000|S2000  |2019-12-16T13:59:59|2019-12-16T14:00:00|joao |733.600.420-26|não               |
# +--------+-----+-------+-------------------+-------------------+-----+--------------+------------------+
```

I'm struggling trying to `pivoting` without success.

Comment: Are you dropping all the null values in the `name` column and populate the dates corresponding to the `cpf` column in the `last_answer_dt` to get the resultant dataframe?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `named aggregations` for this where you specify the aggregation function for each column:

```
df = df.replace('ZZZ', np.NaN)

df = (
    df.groupby(['customer', 'flow', 'session']).agg(
        first_answer_dt=('timestamp', 'min'),
        last_answer_df=('timestamp', 'max'),
        name=('name', 'first'),
        cpf=('cpf', 'first'),
        delivery=('delivery', 'first')
    ).dropna()
    .reset_index()
)


  customer   flow session           first_answer_dt            last_answer_df  \
0    C1000  F1000   S1000 2019-12-16 13:59:58+00:00 2019-12-16 14:00:01+00:00   
1    C1000  F1000   S2000 2019-12-16 13:59:58+00:00 2019-12-16 14:00:00+00:00   

    name             cpf delivery  
0  maria  305.584.960-40      sim  
1   joao  733.600.420-26      não
```